# Not seeing slack notifications when app is in the background and the chat with sender is open

Tags: macos, slack

In short:
When a direct chat with someone is open, in the background, I don't see new messages notifications from that someone.

Longer version using a scenario:
I usually work in maximize mode, meaning, I only see one app at a time. This is great for focus. Especially when developing.
I'm chatting with a team mate who sent me a message. I see the notification, click on it and see the message. I then copy something that he sent me, say thanks and try to run what he sent me on a different window. In the meantime, I don't see the slack app, as it's below the dev tool I'm using.
In the meantime, my mate, sent me a correction to what he sent earlier.
The problem is that I don't get any notification that he sent me a new message, breaking my head over the previous sample, trying to understand why isn't it working.
If I would have closed the direct chat with my mate, I would have seen a notification.

Comment: Moved from here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/156032

Comment: This seems like a feature request for slack. Basically you want a way to configure notifications to fire even from your current view - I don’t see this as an option. I personally always default my view to “All unreads” (CMD + Shift + A) and even often close the window (CMD + W) and later reopen it (CMD + 1) - so this isn’t a problem for me (suggesting you do something similar). I’m not sure I personally would want a notification if I already have the chat open.

Comment: Actually I can’t reproduce this. I sent a message to a bot, switched to another app, and I got a notification from the bot auto response. Can you clarify how to repro?